# PHP Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Tags: php, apache, linux

I running an instance of Wordpress on my web server but I'm getting this error in the logs

```
PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in 
/home/webserver/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173, 
referer: http:// mysite.com/
```

I check the `class-wp-filesystem-direct.php` file on 173

here is the line:

```
if ( ! $recursive || ! $this->is_dir( $file ) ) {
                        return chmod( $file, $mode );
}
```

This are the permissions of this file:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root apache 17K Oct 20 20:24 /home/webserver/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php
```

Any of you knows what is wrong with my instance of Wordpress?

I'll really appreciated your help.

Comment: This isn't about file permissions but rather file ownership. E.g. if I have a file with permissions 777 owned by `root` and in the `root` group, then the apache user won't be able to change its permissions

Comment: @TomJNowell, but the question is what file do I need to change permissions? or change ownership ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to tell from just the information you've given, what were you trying to do when it happened? A WP update?

Comment: can confirm this when trying to update wp over backend-dashboard

Comment: My solution was to upload the whole wp-includes folder from version 5.7 again. My luck was that I write plugins and usually don't care about the core locally, so after the failed update I could just re-upload the 5.7 core and it worked again

Comment: @clockw0rk Could you please elaborate on your solution? I'm having the same problem now.

Comment: I had a working wp lying around on my hard drive. the only thing i ever uploaded / committed was my plugin. so when the update failed, i could just upload the whole wp-includes folder and just override it on the server - "hard-downgrade" so to speak.

Comment: FYI i could get rid of the error by just setting chmod -R 777 to folders admin and include, then updating via the backend, then again chmod -R 750 the folders to deny scripts write-permissions on them. if you don't care just have 777 on them permanently

Answer (score 1):

In my case, these were files in /wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/ folder.

Comment: You mean you had files there with wrong permissions? Why would WordPress be trying to chmod those?

Comment: @Rup bb-plugin tried to access these files using WP files API. I don't remember if the plugin tried to create new files or change existing ones.

Comment: hmm, i ls -l every file in uploads but I can't find the file that's causes the error. I developing locally with XAMPP on a macbook. But all of a sudden I can't update my plugins

Comment: same issue for me, Beaver Builder

Answer (score 0):

You must change the ownership from "root" to "www-data" . www-data is the web user for apache2.

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/html/[yourwebsitefolder]/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php
```

or better change all the wp-admin folder files recursively

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/html/[yourwebsitefolder]/wp-admin/  -R
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the user which your web server is running as, and the owner user and group for the files inside your wp-content folder.

If the webserver's user is not the same as the file owner, or in the same group, then this error is because the script, when trying to regenerate the different sizes of the original image does not have permission to replace the files and so throws the above error.